# Instashell Error : "I require openssl but it's not installed. Run ./install.sh Aborting."

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl

I have an error with instashell : "I require openssl but it's not installed. Run ./install.sh Aborting."

I obviously ran the install.sh script before trying to launch the program but it doesn't seem to have worked.

Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/btRNI.png

Here is the commands I have tested :

`sudo apt-get install openssl`, `pip install pyOpenSSL` etc ..

I really need help, anyone have a solution please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
pkg install openssl-tool
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).